# Is it possible to charge a capacitor to any potential? Does it depend on the dielectric placed between them?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential, capacitance

Is it possible to charge a capacitor to any potential? Does it depend on the dielectric placed between them? Or, are there other factors affecting it?

Comment: See: [http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/51287/what-defines-the-maximum-charge-a-capacitor-can-store](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/51287/what-defines-the-maximum-charge-a-capacitor-can-store)

Comment: So now if it is not a parallel plate capacitor..its a solid sphere with radius R...can it be limitlessly charged?

Comment: No, at some point the electric field inside the insulator becomes large enoughy to make it a conductor, and the charge will dissipate.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can charge capacitor to any potential if in a vaccum .

But placing a dielectric inside it defines its **dielectric strength** and **breakdown voltage** above which the covalent bonds in dielectric material breaks down to bring large amount of charge carriers and thus is starts acting as conductor and capacitance becomes infinite.

Comment: I believe this is wrong, because if you get high enough voltages, the electrons Will shoot from one terminal to the other.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible because. For eg in 1000 ltr tank you can only put 1000 ltr water or liquid not more than that as same way in capacitors you can only charge as much as its capacity.  So it is not possible.

Comment: This is incorrect. What value would you cite as the limit on a capacitor? As long as the charge won't leak across the gap between the electrodes, you can keep adding charge.  There is a practical limit: dielectric strength of gap material.